# How can assign a class value to another nested classes in C++

Tags: c++

this is the first time to ask my question on Stackoverflow. my qustion is i got this message when i trying to run this code:

object.h

```
#ifndef __NCTUNS_nslobject_h__
#define __NCTUNS_nslobject_h__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <event.h>

//---------------------------------------------------
#include <cstdlib>      //srand()
#include <iostream>     //cout
#include <ctime>        //time()
#include <cstring>      //strcmp()
//#include "test.h"       //testing functions
#include "RSA.h"        //GenerateKeyPair()
#include "PrimeGenerator.h"     //Generate()
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


//---------------------------------------------------

class MBinder;

struct plist {
u_int8_t        pid;
struct plist            *next;
};

struct MBlist {
u_int8_t    portnum;
MBinder     *sendt;
struct MBlist   *next;
};
 /*=========================================================================
 Define Macros
  =========================================================================*/
#define DISABLED        0x00
#define ENABLED         0x01


/*=========================================================================
Define Class ProtoType
=========================================================================*/

class NslObject {

private: 

char        *name_;     /* Instance name */
const u_int32_t nodeID_;    /* Node Id */
const u_int32_t nodeType_;  /* Node type, eg: SWITCH, HOST.. */
u_int32_t   portid_;    /* port Id */
struct plist    *MPlist_;
    //const  KeyPair  newKeyPair;


public :
/* add for new structure engine*/
    u_int32_t       pdepth;
    struct MBlist   *BinderList;
    u_int8_t       PortNum;

//------------------------------------------------
    static KeyPair  newKeyPair ;
    //static KeyPair  *KeyPtr1 ;//= new KeyPair;
    //------------------------------------------------
u_char          s_flowctl;      /* flow control for sending pkt */
u_char          r_flowctl;      /* flow control for receiving pkt */

MBinder     *recvtarget_;   /* to upper component */
MBinder     *sendtarget_;   /* to lower component */


NslObject(u_int32_t, u_int32_t, struct plist*, const char *);
NslObject();
virtual         ~NslObject();   
virtual int     init();
virtual int     recv(ePacket_ *); 
virtual int     send(ePacket_ *); 
virtual int     get(ePacket_ *, MBinder *);
virtual int     put(ePacket_ *, MBinder *);
virtual ePacket_    *put1(ePacket_ *, MBinder *);
virtual int     command(int argc, const char *argv[]); 
virtual int     Debugger();


inline  void    set_port(u_int32_t portid) { 
        portid_ = portid; 
    };   
inline u_int32_t get_port() const { 
        return(portid_); 
    }; 
inline struct plist* get_portls() const {
        return(MPlist_);
    };
inline const char * get_name() const {
        return(name_);
    }
inline u_int32_t get_nid() const {
        return(nodeID_);
    }
inline u_int32_t get_type() const {
        return(nodeType_);
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------

  static  void Set_KeyPair(void);

//  NslObject(const KeyPair &newKeyPair):
//  newKeyPair(newKeyPair) {
//  }
 //NslObject( KeyPair &other, u_int32_t &N_ID, u_int32_t &N_Type) : newKeyPair(other),nodeID_     (N_ID),nodeType_ (N_Type)  {}



 /*  Key(const BigInt &modulus, const BigInt &exponent) :
modulus(modulus), exponent(exponent) {
}*/

};


/* Added by CCLin to uniformly format
* debugging messages.
*/

 #define NSLOBJ_DEBUG_STRING_HEAD() do {                \
double sec;                     \
TICK_TO_SEC(sec, GetCurrentTime());         \
printf("%11.7f: [%03d]%s::%s: ",            \
        sec, get_nid(),             \
        getModuleName(this), __FUNCTION__); \
} while(0)

 #endif /* __NCTUNS_object_h__ */
```

in Object.cc

```
void Set_KeyPair()
{
unsigned long int keyLength = 10;
//static KeyPair ADD(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));
NslObject::newKeyPair  (RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));

//NslObject::KeyPtr
//NslObject::newKeyPair;
}
```

so, my problem is when the compiler starts compiling it stops on this code :

```
NslObject::newKeyPair  (RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));
```

and the appeared message is :

```
Error:
object.cc: In function ‘void Set_KeyPair()’:
object.cc:53: error: no match for call to ‘(KeyPair) (KeyPair&)’
```

so, how could i assign a generated keypair class value to NslObject::newKeyPair.

your helping is highly appreciated in advance & thank you .

Comment: Try to declare a variable? NslObject::newKeyPair var(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));

Comment: What is the return type of RSA::GenerateKeyPair?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: No, `newKeyPair` is a member variable, not a type.

Comment: thank you for your rapid replay... the return type of RSA::GenerateKeyPair is KeyPair class

Comment: oops!!!. when i tried this code : NslObject::newKeyPair = RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength); i got this message : ./KeyPair.h:39: error: non-static const member ‘const Key KeyPair::privateKey’, can't use default assignment operator????

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign it with a new value, then you need to use assignment:

```
NslObject::newKeyPair = RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength);
```

Your code tries to call it like a function instead, with doesn't work because it isn't a functor.

(Also, you shouldn't use [reserved names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) for your include guards.)

Comment: thank you for your rapid replay... the return type of RSA::GenerateKeyPair is KeyPair class .

Comment: oops!!!. when i tried this code : NslObject::newKeyPair = RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength); i got this message :  ./KeyPair.h:39: error: non-static const member ‘const Key KeyPair::privateKey’, can't use default assignment operator????

Comment: @user2590797: That's referring to code that you haven't posted, so I can only guess; but it looks like you're trying to assign to a `const` variable. `const` means you can't modify it.