# error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

Tags: c++

I have tried many times to solve this problem but i got nothing.

The main purpose of this code is saving pair keys (Public and Private) in nested class `NslObject::KeyK` or `NewKeyPair1`.

**.cpp file**

```
        unsigned long int keyLength = 10;
        //KeyPair ADD(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));
        NslObject::KeyK(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));
        typedef NslObject::KeyK NewKeyPair1; 
        NewKeyPair1(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));

        //NslObject::
        Key OtmanK(NslObject::Get_PublicKey(NewKeyPair1));
```

**.h file:**

```
 #ifndef    __NCTUNS_nslobject_h__
 #define __NCTUNS_nslobject_h__

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <event.h>

 //---------------------------------------------------
 #include <cstdlib>      //srand()
 #include <iostream>     //cout
 #include <ctime>        //time()
 #include <cstring>      //strcmp()
 //#include "test.h"       //testing functions
 #include "RSA.h"        //GenerateKeyPair()
 #include "PrimeGenerator.h"     //Generate()
 //#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sstream> 
 #include <string>


 //---------------------------------------------------

 class MBinder;

  struct plist {
u_int8_t        pid;
struct plist            *next;
 };

  struct MBlist {
u_int8_t    portnum;
MBinder     *sendt;
struct MBlist   *next;
 };
 /*=========================================================================
 Define Macros
 =========================================================================*/
 #define DISABLED       0x00
 #define ENABLED            0x01


 /*=========================================================================
 Define Class ProtoType
 =========================================================================*/

 class NslObject {

 private: 

char        *name_;     /* Instance name */
const u_int32_t nodeID_;    /* Node Id */
const u_int32_t nodeType_;  /* Node type, eg: SWITCH, HOST.. */
u_int32_t   portid_;    /* port Id */
struct plist    *MPlist_;
   // static  KeyPair  NewKeyPair;


  public :
/* add for new structure engine*/
    u_int32_t       pdepth;
    struct MBlist   *BinderList;
    u_int8_t       PortNum;

//------------------------------------------------
    class KeyK {
    private :
         KeyPair Kk; 

    public:

      KeyK( KeyPair D1): Kk(D1)
      {}

     const  Key &GetPrivateKey() const
            {
                    return Kk.GetPrivateKey();
            }

     const  Key &GetPublicKey() const
            {
                    return Kk.GetPublicKey();
            }

       //KeyK  NewKeyPair ;


     };

     Key Get_PrivateKey(KeyK &K){
        return K.GetPrivateKey();
     }
      Key Get_PublicKey(KeyK &K){
        return K.GetPublicKey();
     }


    //static KeyPair  *KeyPtr1 ;//= new KeyPair;
    //------------------------------------------------
u_char          s_flowctl;      /* flow control for sending pkt */
u_char          r_flowctl;      /* flow control for receiving pkt */

MBinder     *recvtarget_;   /* to upper component */
MBinder     *sendtarget_;   /* to lower component */


NslObject(u_int32_t, u_int32_t, struct plist*, const char *);
NslObject();
virtual         ~NslObject();   
virtual int     init();
virtual int     recv(ePacket_ *); 
virtual int     send(ePacket_ *); 
virtual int     get(ePacket_ *, MBinder *);
virtual int     put(ePacket_ *, MBinder *);
virtual ePacket_    *put1(ePacket_ *, MBinder *);
virtual int     command(int argc, const char *argv[]); 
virtual int     Debugger();


inline  void    set_port(u_int32_t portid) { 
        portid_ = portid; 
    };   
inline u_int32_t get_port() const { 
        return(portid_); 
    }; 
inline struct plist* get_portls() const {
        return(MPlist_);
    };
inline const char * get_name() const {
        return(name_);
    }
inline u_int32_t get_nid() const {
        return(nodeID_);
    }
inline u_int32_t get_type() const {
        return(nodeType_);
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------





  };
```

so, the problem in this line in cpp file :

```
 Key OtmanK(NslObject::Get_PublicKey(NewKeyPair1));
```

when i tried to compile this project, i got this Error message:

```
 object.cc:87: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

please, help me.

when i tried to make a directed call for key class, the other problem was appeared such as :

```
        unsigned long int keyLength = 10;
        //KeyPair ADD(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));
        NslObject::KeyK(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));
        typedef NslObject::KeyK NewKeyPair1; 
        NewKeyPair1(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));

        //NslObject::
        //Key OtmanK(NewKeyPair1.GetPublicKey());
        std::string message = "othman Alkilany";
        // NslObject::NewKeyPair.GetPrivateKey()
       std::string cypherText = RSA::Encrypt(  message, NewKeyPair1.GetPublicKey());
```

the Error Message is :

```
  error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
```

Comment: dup of ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697337/how-can-assign-a-class-value-to-another-nested-classes-in-c/17697417#17697417

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You are more likely to get meaningful answers if you trim your question down. One suggestion might be to selectively delete/comment out parts of the code until you arrive at the smallest example which reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your issue is in the second line here:

```
typedef NslObject::KeyK NewKeyPair1; 
NewKeyPair1(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));
```

Resolving the typedef you've essentially written the following:

```
NslObject::KeyK(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));
```

So you can clearly see you're missing the variable name for this line.

To fix this, name the variable/object:

```
NewKeyPair1 somekeypair(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));
```

However, I guess you misused the `typedef` anyway? Did you try to name that `NewKeyPair1`? Something like this:

```
NslObject::KeyK NewKeyPair1(RSA::GenerateKeyPair(keyLength));
```